# How to deal with daft header files

Tags: c++, include

I'm trying to use a third party SDK in some C++ code. While the SDK and headers are technically compatible with C++, it's really just a lump of nasty C.

In particular the main header files has many hundreds of #defines of which these are the worst.

```
#define     C  0       //Celsius
#define     F  1       //Fahrenheit
#define     R  2       // Rankine
#define     K  3       // Kelvin
```

Now, you can imagine what nice error messages I get when trying to use boost libraries that have things like this in them:

```
template< typename F > struct template_arity;
```

A few tactical #undefs could fix things, but it still feels like a ticking bomb. I could alternatively rewrite large parts of the third-party header, or maybe just try and isolate the sections I really need.

Is there any better solution to this problem?

Comment: At least that header follows the "macro names should be all-caps" rule.  :|  That's really terrible... I'd probably steer clear of that library if I could.

Comment: @James, except it's the vendor's API for the hardware I need to control :-(

Comment: @Roddy:  Sorry, I wish I had a better answer.

Comment: Jüergen's rule: Any API which defines either the Fahrenheit or Rankine scales for temperature is an API which should be forever banished. Seriously, I've come across APIs which define the multipliers for kilo, mega, milli etc. as configurable parameters. Just in case...

Answer (score 8):

What about only incuding the offnding files in a single .cpp file, and then just expose the functionality you need through a separate header?

Answer (score 2):

Have the original author rewrite it for you?

Seriously, this looks like a case of very poor design. I'd rewrite the macros, perhaps as `enum`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the 3rd party library behind your own interface. This allows you to include only the 3rd party header in a source file, with no risk of messing with anything else. Actually this is good advice: Never include a 3rd party header in your own header. Always, and only, include 3rd party headers in your source files (.cpp).

Good luck!

Comment: But what if some of the members of my header are of classes declared in third-party headers?

Comment: I would hide such members behind a private implementation. This may sound like a lot of extra work, but I've found it to be worth while, especially in the long run. Here's a good explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need these values in your code or are they only used in their header internally?

You could write a new header to include after that one which undef's the offending definitions before including anything else.

Probably not practical but macros cause this kind of pain so there may notbe much to do :(